# RegEx find and replace filename in SQL file via Adobe Brackets

Tags: sql, regex, replace, find, adobe-brackets

I'm trying to find all the **filenames ONLY, *without the paths***, from an **SQL** file by means of **RegEx**. Let's just say I'm trying to search and replace my findings using [**Adobe Brackets**](http://brackets.io/) *Replace* function. What would be the **RegEx** to go about this?

The **SQL** file would contain hundreds of **very long lines** like so:

```
(493, 179, '_wp_attached_file', '2014/08/The_Image_Name_Here-004.jpg'),
(494, 179, '_wp_attachment_metadata', 'a:5:
    {s:5:"width";i:365;s:6:"height";i:205;s:4:"file";s:31:"2014/08/The_Image_Name_Here-004.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:6:
    {s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:
    {s:4:"file";s:31:"The_Image_Name_Here-004-139x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:139;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:
    {s:4:"file";s:31:"The_Image_Name_Here-004-240x134.jpg";s:5:"width";i:240;s:6:"height";i:134;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:15:"featured-medium";a:4:
    {s:4:"file";s:31:"The_Image_Name_Here-004-230x160.jpg";s:5:"width";i:230;s:6:"height";i:160;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:13:"featured-head";a:4:
    {s:4:"file";s:31:"The_Image_Name_Here-004-365x193.jpg";s:5:"width";i:365;s:6:"height";i:193;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:4:"icon";a:4:
    {s:4:"file";s:29:"The_Image_Name_Here-004-81x87.jpg";s:5:"width";i:81;s:6:"height";i:87;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:10:"icon-large";a:4:
    {s:4:"file";s:31:"The_Image_Name_Here-004-120x131.jpg";s:5:"width";i:120;s:6:"height";i:131;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:10:
    {s:8:"aperture";i:0;s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";i:0;s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";i:0;s:3:"iso";i:0;s:13:"shutter_speed";i:0;s:5:"title";s:0:"";}}'
),
```

> Note: The above is just a sample of part of the content and is
> originally **two lines** but seperated into multiple lines for easier
> viewing

The expression that I tried is this:

```
/(?=\/|"|').*?(\.jpg)/g
```

And I expect to find these from the above sample:

```
The_Image_Name_Here-004.jpg
The_Image_Name_Here-004.jpg
The_Image_Name_Here-004-139x100.jpg
The_Image_Name_Here-004-240x134.jpg
The_Image_Name_Here-004-230x160.jpg
The_Image_Name_Here-004-365x193.jpg
The_Image_Name_Here-004-81x87.jpg
The_Image_Name_Here-004-120x131.jpg
```

But my result end up like this:

```
'_wp_attached_file', '2014/08/The_Image_Name_Here-004.jpg
"width";i:365;s:6:"height";i:205;s:4:"file";s:31:"2014/08/The_Image_Name_Here-004.jpg
"file";s:31:"The_Image_Name_Here-004-139x100.jpg
"file";s:31:"The_Image_Name_Here-004-240x134.jpg
"file";s:31:"The_Image_Name_Here-004-230x160.jpg
"file";s:31:"The_Image_Name_Here-004-365x193.jpg
"file";s:29:"The_Image_Name_Here-004-81x87.jpg
"file";s:31:"The_Image_Name_Here-004-120x131.jpg
```

Demo: http://refiddle.co/refiddles/54a94f7075622d09faf30c00

Any way I can get only the **filenames** *(including the extension)*?

Comment: Which language's regex are you using?

Comment: I'm not really sure but I think [**Adobe Brackets**](http://brackets.io/) uses **Javascript**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using regex's with lookbehind (so, not javascript) you can use this regex:

```
/(?<="|').+\.jpg(?="|')/g
```

Otherwise you can just use:

```
/[\w-]+\.jpg/g
```

The second one actually seems far more elegant to me, [here it is at action](http://regexr.com/3a5ib).

Comment: It's not **javascript** so **lookbehind** will not work, but the second one does the job! Cheers!

Comment: @gmaggio I think you meant: It *is* javascript, so lookbehind will not work ;)